# How to skip the name of folder in routes path in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a frontend part in my rails app. The controllers like posts, comments, etc., will be in a folder I named it public. Therefore, the folders of posts in view is inside public folder as well, but I would like routes come after the root like:

`localhost:3000/posts`

NOT: `localhost:3000/public/posts`

It means I would like to skip public folder in routes.

Comment: Keep in mind that for many hosting environments `public` is accessible ad static files so you may be exposing your source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes file, you can write the following:

```
scope module: 'public' do
  resources :posts
end
```

Now, it will generate routes without the word `public`.

Not, for it to work, `PostsController` must be inside a folder name: `public`, and its name should be something like following:

```
class Public::PostsController < ApplicationController
end
```

Comment: @AdamGol If my answer helped you, you can accept it.